# Inserting to database on a single page form application

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've designed a form to insert data to a database on localhost.

```
<form action='' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='CRUD' value='New Data'>
<br><br>
<input type='submit' name='CRUD' value='Retrieve Data'>
<br>

<hr>
</form>

<?php
error_reporting(0);
$x = $_POST['CRUD'];

if ($x == "New Data") {
    require 'part1.php';
}
?>
```

I then made a form to insert the data on another file.

```
<form method='post'>
<label for='site'>Name: </label>
<input type='text' name='site'> 
<br><br>

<label for='date'>Date: </label>
<input type='date' name='time'>
<br><br>

<label for='page'>Web URL: </label>
<input type='url' name='page'>
<br><br>

<label for='desc'>Description: </label>
<input type='text' name='desc'>
<br><br>

<input type='submit' name='finish' value='Go'><input type="reset">
</form>

<?php

if ( !empty( $_POST) ){

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "assignment5";

    $resource = $_POST['site'];
    $date = $_POST['time'];
    $url = $_POST['page'];
    $explain = $_POST['desc'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', $password, $dbname) or 
    die("Unable to connect");

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO thedata (date, Name, URL, Description)
    VALUES ('$date', '$resource', '$url', '$explain')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

On there own they work as intended but what I need is to have both forms on the same page. Doing this gives an error where default data is inserted and not the form's inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the 2 forms in the same page , you have to give each form a submit button .. be aware to use the same submit button to the same forms